# How to manipulate value get from a js function in php

Tags: javascript, php

I called a js function from php code and its returning value from a js function but the problem is after getting value if i add some number with that value it doesnot showing me the expected result. Here is the code:-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<script>
    function returnValue(){
        document.getElementById("getVal").innerText=parseInt(5);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="returnValue()">
<?php 
    $val="<span id='getVal'><script>returnVal()</script></span>";
    echo $val+2; //return 2 not 7;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, while javascript runs on the client. This is not how both can be used together. Also you are concatinating a string and a number.

Comment: @Imperative so cant I perform some calculation on that.

Comment: in other words your php is finished before your browser even knows that there comes javascript

Comment: @delueg can u please help by code.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: if you just stuck in how to passign values from javascript to php and back... i would advice you to take a look here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ .... i also wrote a little hleper to modulise and easify it https://github.com/delueg/ajax-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix php and js that way as the php must be executed before sending the html and the javascript is executed once the user has received the html.

I advise you to use ajax. That way you would send returnValue() value to a php script where you can process it and even send back its output to javascript.

Comment: Great! Let us know if you get stuck!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an AJAX Call. Im doing it with jQuery, but you can also do it with plain java script, just google the syntax.

The Problem you're facing is that JavaScript and PHP run on different locations.

PHP runs on the Server, JavaScript on the client, so PHP will be finished before the html file has arrived by the client. The Client doesn't know about PHP.

Communication between JavaScript and PHP is handled by AJAX Calls. Just look it up if you need further explanation.

Beneath the JavaScript Code for the Ajax Code:

```
var data = returnValue();

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: yourfile.php,
            data: {data : data}
        })
        .done(function(response){
            //do something with your code like document.wirte(response)
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown); //Error handling
        });
```

Here some PHP:

```
$value = $_POST['data'];
$value = $value +2;
echo $value;
```