# How would I post a Javascript variable to my PHP file to use?

Tags: javascript, php, post, get

I am very unfamiliar with PHP and doing posting with Javascript. I have two `.php` files that I am using - one is my main `.php` file called `page.tpl.php` and the other is the php file that has my Javascript in it called `winWidth.php`. I want to POST the window width of the browser to my `page.tpl.php` and then use it to conditionally sort of if a window width is larger than `768`.

I am getting the window width just fine in my `winWidth.php`:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
```

But I am not sure what I need to do with it next. Nor am I sure what to do with it in my `page.tpl.php`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Search the net/SO for post ajax php

Comment: Why does the window width need to be used in php anyway? If it's to display it then javascript is just fine using `write()` ?

Comment: @Onimusha - as stated in my question above, I need to conditionally check the window width for something else in my php script on the other page. specifically i need to tell the difference between android phones and android tablets

Comment: @scapegoat17 you could perhaps use a device detection service/library like WURFL for that.

Comment: @cbuckley - I have never heard of it. How does that work out?

Comment: @scapegoat17 plenty of links at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WURFL

Answer (score -1):

I answered this on a [simliar Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488336/how-to-manipulate-value-get-from-a-js-function-in-php/23489012#23489012)

But what you need ist an Ajax Call from JavaScript with jQuery, it would look like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: yourfile.php,
            data: {data : data}
        })
        .done(function(response){
            //do something with your code like document.wirte(response)
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown); //Error handling
        });
```

In plain JavaScript you could do the following

**EDIT**

```
var xmlhttp;
var data; //The Data you need to transmit to the php file
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",'yourfile',true);
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

You can take the given data in PHP then with

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: Is $.ajax a jQuery post? I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry i didn't mentioned that, i'll update my Answer.

Comment: Edited the answer with Internet Exploer 6 and 7 support.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What would be what I use to get the post in my php code?

Comment: I updated my answer, i had an error in the transmission of the POST Data, now it is fixed. In you PHP file you can access the Data with the last line of code in my answer, `$data = $_POST['data']`

Comment: I still cant seem to find anything that is posting under my network tab... would you have any ideas why that would be?